Sum row values if there are same strings in a column
I have a dataframe looking like



Sample
Value
Domain




S1
12
Domain_Identified_X13_A


S1
25
Domain_Identified_X28_B


S1
18
Domain_Unidentified



I want to aggregate values for the rows including string of "Identified" to have a final df



Sample
Value
Domain




S1
37
Domain_Identified


S1
18
Domain_Unidentified



Thank you

Using summarize from dplyr and sub to get the groups.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Sample, Domain = sub("(.*dentified).*", "\\1", Domain)) %>% 
  summarize(Value = sum(Value), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Sample Domain              Value
  <chr>  <chr>               <int>
1 S1     Domain_Identified      37
2 S1     Domain_Unidentified    18

Alternative a base R approach using aggregate
setNames(aggregate(df$Value, by=
           list(df$Sample, sub("(.*dentified).*", "\\1", df$Domain)), \(x) 
             sum(x)), c(colnames(df)[c(1,3)], "Value"))
  Sample              Domain Value
1     S1   Domain_Identified    37
2     S1 Domain_Unidentified    18


Extract the indicated strings, , perform the sum and reorder the columns so Domain comes last.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DF %>%
  mutate(Domain = str_extract(Domain, "Domain_(Identified|Unidentified)")) %>%
  summarize(Value = sum(Value), .by = c(Sample, Domain)) %>%
  select(Sample, Value, Domain)

giving
  Sample Value              Domain
1     S1    37   Domain_Identified
2     S1    18 Domain_Unidentified

Note
The input in reproducible form is
DF <- data.frame(
  Sample = rep("S1", 3L),
  Value = c(12L, 25L, 18L),
  Domain = c("Domain_Identified_X13_A", 
    "Domain_Identified_X28_B", "Domain_Unidentified")
)


You could create a dummy indicator for the unidentified cases
df$dummy=ifelse(df$domain=="Domain_Unidentified",1,0)

and then use dplyr to sum across groups
library(dplyr)

df%>%
group_by(dummy)%>%
mutate(total_value=sum(value)


